# Is it possible to make an EditText in android 2.x that looks like an EditText from Android 4?

Tags: android, styles, android-edittext

Is it possible to make an `EditText` in android 2.x that looks like an `EditText` from Android 4?  I mean blue backlight with flanged edges below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a library called holoeverywhere, you'll get all 4.2 components in 2.1+:

https://github.com/ChristopheVersieux/HoloEverywhere

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want to use an external library you can use the following code:

add the below code to `res\values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="HoloEditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

After that from `YOURPATH\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\` just copy the `edit_text_holo_dark.xml` and all referenced drawables to the corresponding directories in your project.

And then simply apply the style to your EditText:

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   style="@style/HoloEditText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: how can i do the same for seek bar. because in android-16. It is showing seek_thumb as only drawable, which is not giving required result.

Comment: Check the "Widget.Holo.Light.SeekBar" lines in the "/res/values/styles.xml" file. Copy that six lines and the two referenced scrubber-drawables as well. This should work.

Comment: and 1 more question can i change the color of seek bar to green..??

Comment: Of course just check this site http://android-holo-colors.com/ and copy every file from the zip-archive to your project. Actually this is even easier than the "way" I suggested before. ;]