# Make edittext look like holo light in all versions of Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

An edittext looks different in a 2.2 emulator than it does in a 4.2 version. I want to make my edittext look like it does in the holo light version on a 4.2 emulator.

I have no idea how to do this, do I need to write my own custom style? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure that you want to do this? Users of 2.2 devices may not recognize an `EditText` with holo styling. Remember that there are *very* few people who have *both* a 2.x and a 4.x device. Usually, you want a look and feel that will be natural for the user.

That being said, if you are sure that you want to do this, you are welcome to try to get [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere) working.

Comment: _...you are welcome to try to get HoloEverywhere working._
Amen Mr. Mark Murphy, I couldn't get it to download through the instructions given on its page

Answer (score 1):

I found this web:

[Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

Comment: Cool! I've yet to try it out, but it looks perfect for what I need! No big files or troubles installing, like with HoloEverywhere. :)

Answer (score 0):

check out these links :

**1.** [How to create ICS holo style edit text for older versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13135972/how-to-create-ics-holo-style-edit-text-for-older-versions)

**2.** [How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners)

**3.** [Styling EditText view with shape drawable to look similar to new holographic theme for Android < 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211929/styling-edittext-view-with-shape-drawable-to-look-similar-to-new-holographic-the/8212093)

Answer (score 0):

[Is it possible to make an EditText in android 2.x that looks like an EditText from Android 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821395/is-it-possible-to-make-an-edittext-in-android-2-x-that-looks-like-an-edittext-fr/13822264#13822264)

**Check the above answer to the Question,**

> Or You can use the following method (referred from the above question):

add the below code to `res\values\styles.xml`

```
<style name="HoloEditText">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/edit_text_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

After that from `YOURPATH\android-sdk\platforms\android-16\data\res\` just copy the `edit_text_holo_light.xml` and all referenced drawables to the corresponding directories in your project.

And then simply apply the style to your EditText:

```
 <EditText
   android:id="@+id/editText"
   style="@style/HoloEditText"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```