# Why are android themes not backward compatible?

Tags: android, themes, compatibility

I am developing an android application for android 2.3 (v8) and compiling against android 4.0 (v14). I did some research on trying to apply `Holo.Light` for my app, but the only solutions I have come across so far are either creating my own custom theme or using this open source project called HoloEverywhere.

Now what I am confused about is why are themes not backward compatible? Is it because there are new android attributes or views added to the newer APIs, or is it because of some other reason?

Any explanation on this would be really helpful! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

> "Newer versions of Android have additional themes available to
>   applications, and you might want to use these while running on those
>   platforms while still being compatible with older versions. You can
>   accomplish this through a custom theme that uses resource selection to
>   switch between different parent themes, based on the platform version"

So what you should do is have two copies of styles.xml, one will be placed in res/values/styles.xml - for backward compatibility of android versions < 3.0, with the default theme:

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Light">
...
</style>
```

And than put another styles.xml under res/values-v11 for android versions >= 3.0 with Holo theme:

```
<style name="LightThemeSelector" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
...
</style>
```

This way you gain and use Holo theme where possible, which is today 88% of the overall android market.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but is there a way to achieve Holo on devices < 4.0 ? I have seen applications which have newer themes on older apis. Are these custom styles or is there a version of these themes available for older apis?

Comment: I just came across this post. Cleared my doubt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821395/is-it-possible-to-make-an-edittext-in-android-2-x-that-looks-like-an-edittext-fr Anyways thanks for your help :)

Comment: Using custom theme you can do whatever you want. there is no reason you won't be able to have holo theme like that. this is how HoloEverywhere library is doing it. 
The link you provided is broken, but here is a link to HoloEverywhere:https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere